# What can I do when I found an error in the function?

Tags: r, regression

Currently I'm studying Applied Linear Regression Models, Kutner.

I used library(ALSM), during working on example in chapter 4.3 with computer, I found `ci.reg` function has some error in calculating simultaneous prediction intervals for new observations.

And I figured out that in

```
else if (match.arg(type) == "s") {
    s <- spred
    z <- s
}
```

part, two rows should be interchanged.

I have my personal library in github, so that I can avoid same problems from now on, but what can I do more in order to notify that this function has this kind of matter in this part? I found ALSM library in github as well, but I can't comment there...

Thank you.

Comment: You can make a pull request. https://github.com/bryangoodrich/ALSM/pulls You probably found the version from CRAN, which is just a [read-only mirror](https://github.com/cran/ALSM).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thank you!